# "reason: 'fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist" getting this error after update(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdkloginkit

[image]

I have looked through all of the previous answers and none of them have worked for me.  The facebook login has worked for months but after my most recent update on the test phone to 9.3.5 the login has stopped working and has started crashing with this error code.  Attached is a screenshot of my .plist but it is correct.  I am wondering if anyone else is having this problem with the updates and if anyone has found a way to fix it.

I think the problem could be in the app delegate so if anyone has a different way to make this call that would be helpful as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi James, Stack Overflow generally frowns upon screenshots of code. Instead, copy the code into your question and use the <code> tool (or markdown) to format your snippets.

Comment: Sorry about that I will make sure to do that next time!